# Struggles with gin session management in redis key "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions" or key Key "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions" does not exist

Tags: go, session, go-gin

I have run into some trouble following a gin-gonic book which has helped so far to move smoothly with gin. When I got to the session part,It seems I hit a blocker.

I am using:

- a macbook pro m1 on MacOs ventura
- Go 1.21.1
- Gin 1.9.1
- gin-contrib/sessions v0.0.5

I have started with the session from gin-contrib/session with the following code

```
//main.go
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions"
    //redisStore "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/redis"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
 )

router := gin.Default()
store, _ := sessions.NewRedisStore(10, "tcp", "localhost:6379", "", []byte("secret"))
//store, _ := redisStore.NewStore(10, "tcp", "localhost:6379", "", []byte("secret"))
router.Use(sessions.Sessions("recipes_api", store))


//auth handler
import (
    //...
    "crypto/sha256"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    //"github.com/gin-contrib/sessions"
    sessions2 "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions"
    //...
)
 
func (handler *AuthHandler) SignInHandler(c *gin.Context) {
//...
    if cur.Err() != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": "Invalid username or password"})
        return
    }
    sessionToken := xid.New().String()
    session := sessions2.Default(c)
    session.Set("username", user.Username)
    session.Set("token", sessionToken)
    session.Save()
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "User signed in"})
}
```

The code above seems to break at the session.Default(c) or session2.Default(c) so whether I am using session from `"github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions"` or from `"github.com/gin-contrib/sessions"`, it consistently doesn't find the key. It throws error like the follwoing

```
Key "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions" does not exist
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:273 (0x10484b67f)
    (*Context).MustGet: panic("Key \"" + key + "\" does not exist")
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/contrib@v0.0.0-20221130124618-7e01895a63f2/sessions/sessions.go:146 (0x10484b61c)
    Default: return c.MustGet(DefaultKey).(Session)
     ~/Tutorials/distributed-golang-app-gin/handlers/auth.go:59 (0x104995dc7)
    (*AuthHandler).SignInHandler: session := sessions2.Default(c)
     ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x104845c5f)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/recovery.go:102 (0x104845c44)
    CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x104844fff)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/logger.go:240 (0x104844fd0)
    LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x104844133)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:620 (0x104843e5c)
    (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:576 (0x104843baf)
    (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2938 (0x1046d95fb)
    serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2009 (0x1046d6777)
    (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 (0x104520b63)
    goexit: MOVD    R0, R0  // NOP
```

I am doing something wrong here and grateful if anyone can shed some light on it for me so I can move this forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. My IDE was auto importing the wrong session reference. I have gone and manually deleted references to  "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions" throughout the project.